# Slick slider: next / prev element title to current div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, advanced-custom-fields, slick.js

I have the following HTML (+ ACF fields) for a slick slider in Wordpress:

```
<?php if (have_rows('videofeed2','option')): ?>
<div class="slider-popular">
            <?php while (have_rows('videofeed2','option')) : the_row(); ?>
                <div class="slider-go-wrap">
                    <div class="pop-title desktop-title">
                        <div class="video-title-wrap">
                            <h2><?php the_sub_field('video_title','option'); ?></h2>
                            <div class="pop-dura"><?php the_sub_field('date','option'); ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="the-video-area">
                        <div class="js-lazyYT youtube" data-youtube-id="<?php the_sub_field('youtube_id','option'); ?>" data-width="300" data-height="200"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="pop-title mobile-pop-title">
                        <h2><?php the_sub_field('video_title','option'); ?></h2>
                        <div class="pop-dura"><?php the_sub_field('date','option'); ?></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="video-controls">
                                <div class="prev-title-popular">
                                    <span class="video-nav-title">Previous video</span>
                                    <span class="lightspan controltitles prev-videotitle">Making a powerful difference</span> <!-- previous video ACF field "title" here -->
                                    <span class="lightspan durations prev-dura">(3:44)</span> <!-- prev video ACF field "dura" here -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="next-title-popular">
                                    <span class="video-nav-title">Next video</span>
                                    <span class="lightspan controltitles next-videotitle">Making a powerful difference</span><!-- next video title here -->
                                    <span class="lightspan durations next-dura">(3:44)</span> <!-- next video duration here -->
                                </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile;?>
</div>     
<?php endif; ?>
```

The video title and duration use ACF field (options page) for content:

```
<?php the_sub_field('video_title','option'); ?>
and
<?php the_sub_field('dura','option'); ?>
```

I would like to get the ACF data from the previous and next fields to corresponding fields in the current slide. I haven't found any good solutions online yet, could this be done maybe with some jQuery?

Comment: Actually, you won't directly get `ACF data from the previous and next fields`. You can simply get prev / next slide durations and put them into the current slide on slick `beforeChange` or `afterChange`.

Comment: My bad, it's totally possible to get directly ACF data in your loop. You have to retrieve ACF from row with previous / next index. As described here : https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/get-data-from-previous-and-next-rows/. Both methods will work, IMHO, do that server side is probably a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

There's 2 ways to achieve that. Using jQuery / Slick API (the client way) or using PHP / ACF methods (the server way).

**1. The client way**

You can retrieve data from previous / next slide DOM on a particular slick event.

E.g. :

```
$('.slider-popular').on('init beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  // find and add prev / next data (using jQuery $html() or $.text()
});
// or on document ready
$('.slider-go-wrap').each(function() {
   // find and add prev / next data (using jQuery $html() or $.text()
});
```

**2. The server way**

You'll have to use a basic PHP foreach loop in order to use an index and retrieve prev / next data by their indexes.

```
$rows = get_field('videofeed2');
if($rows)
{

    foreach($rows as $index => $row)
    {
        // from there, you can get prev / next data using loop index ($rows[$index-1] / $rows[$index+1]
    }

}
```

Hope this will help.

As said in comment, I think the server approach of doing this is probably the cleanest and probably the easiest way (even if I'm a front-end guy).

Comment: So far I've reached this: $('.slider-go-wrap').each(function() {
  currentSlide = $('.slick-current');
   nextSlide = currentSlide.next();
   prevSlide = currentSlide.prev();

   nextSlideData = nextSlide.find('.next-videotitle').html();
   prevSlideData = prevSlide.find('.prev-videotitle').html();
}); but it doesn't seem to be working. Any hints on why ?